# How to install 2nd .exe in Wix InstallExecuteSequence with the 2nd one only occurring after the first one finishes?

Tags: wix3.5

I am creating my first .msi installer using WiX 3.5 setup project in vs2015.

I have 2 `<CustomAction>` defined in my .wxs page, they are both .exe files.

The First .exe file executes fine as it waits for the `After="InstallFinalize"` state.

However the first .exe actually does a job that downloads another .zip file from the web which contains our 2nd .exe.

I need to complete the 2nd `Custom Action` after the first .exe finishes exploding the package. I have tested both custom actions independently and both will install.

```
  <Custom Action="LaunchInstallSoftwareAutoUpdaterProcessAction" After="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="LaunchSoftwareAutoUpdaterProcessAction" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

I am new to WiX but I do not think there is another way to wait that I am aware of. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is it because you have both of them scheduled after InstallFinalize? Schedule one of them After= the other.

Comment: Giving that a try, using the ID of the first in the 2nd After="IDHERE", but no success, the folder structure was installed and the 2nd .exe is sitting in the child directory like it is supposed to. Does the Return matter? On the first one I have Return="asynchNoWait" and on the 2nd it is Return="asynchWait"

Comment: I think you may have that backwards. You should have Wait on the first one. Since the 2nd action relies on the first.